# Windows Scheduler 2nd and 3rd Weekend of each month

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler

Is it possible using the Windows Scheduler to have a task run on the Sunday after the 2nd & 3rd Saturday of each month?

**Long Version**

We have some maintenance scripts which bring our systems offline for patching at 6pm Saturday and back online at 6am Sunday; with maintenance (e.g. windows updates) taking place in between those times.
The systems are typically required on the 1st and last weekend of each month, so we only do maintenance on the 2nd and 3rd weekend of each month.

A potential issue is that if a month starts on a Sunday, on the 3rd Saturday we take the systems offline, but the script to bring them back online on Sunday would have run the week before (i.e. on the 3rd Sunday of the Month).

This is easy to resolve in the script; just schedule the task to run every week, then check if it's the Sunday after the 2nd or 3rd Saturday to determine whether to continue running or to terminate.

However; is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NB: I ended up simply appending a script to the start of my code to determine if we're in the window or not, then having the scheduler run the code every week.

```
param (
    [string]$ScriptPath
    ,[int]$StartDay = 10
    ,[int]$EndDay = 24    
)
#
# Only run the given script if the current date falls on a weekend between the start and end dates (is designed specifically to cope
# with tasks initiated over weekends, so requires that both the saturday and sunday of the current date fall in this window)
#

function Test-DateIsInMaintenanceWindow {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [System.DateTime]$Date = (Get-Date)
        , [int]$StartDay = 10
        , [int]$EndDay = 24
    )
    begin {
        if($StartDay -ge $EndDay) {
            throw "We expect the start date to be before the end date; logic for these dates being the same, or switched (i.e. to cover crossing a month boundary) are beyond the designed requirements"
        }
        $EndDayLocal = $EndDay - 1 #we only test the Sat / we want to ensure we account for the following Sun
    }
    process {
        [boolean]$IsWeekend = $true #assume it's the weekend; we confirm this later
        [DateTime]$Sat = $Date 
        switch ($Date.DayOfWeek) { #we could use 6 and 0 instead of Sat and Sun to avoid language issues; but all our servers are US/UK, and the readability is clearer with week names
            'Saturday' {$Sat = $Date}
            'Sunday' {$Sat = $Date.AddDays(-1)} 
            Default {$IsWeekend = $false}
        }
        write-output (new-object PSObject -prop @{
            Date = $Date
            Day = $Date.DayOfWeek
            OK = $IsWeekend -and (($Sat.Day -ge $StartDay) -and ($Sat.Day -le $EndDayLocal))
        })
    }
}


if ((Test-DateIsInMaintenanceWindow).OK) {
    &$ScriptPath
} else {
    throw 'Script should''t run today' 
}

#Code to say which weekends fall in our maintenance window
1..4000 | %{(get-date).AddDays($_)} | ?{$_.DayOfWeek -like 'S*'} | Test-DateIsInMaintenanceWindow -StartDay 10 -EndDay 24 | ft -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 1):

There's only one month in 2016 that is affected (May). Why not just exclude May from the task schedule and run your scripts manually or create a separate scheduled task for May? You could easily expand this to future years by creating two scheduled tasks. One that runs on your predefined schedule but excludes those months that begin on a Sunday and a second that includes only those months that begin on a Sunday.

There's one affected month in 2016. Two in each of the next 4 years, and one in 2021.

Comment: Thanks for that.  However I try to avoid any solution that needs people to remember to go in and tweak; as such things often run well for years, then cause issues when they've been forgotten about / become taken for granted (good processes and documentation could protect against that; but that's rare).

Comment: True enough. The option to create multiple tasks seems like an easy enough solution though. Maybe that's a good route to go.